# Safely creating S3 Generics in R

Tags: r, generics, r-s3

Henrik Bengtsson has provided the internet with a nice way of [creating S3 generics in R](http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/R/setGenericS3/) without having to bother whether they were already created before... in 2002.

What his function setGenericsS3 does, is basically:

- check whether the name is fine
- check whether there is a function with that name

if so,

- check whether it is a generic
- in case it's not, rename it as .default and create a generic

if not, just create the generic.

This code proved very useful to automatically create generics when there was none available in your own packages. As we moved quite past this R era, I was wondering what the correct way is to achieve the same in R now. I can't find an `isS3Generic()` or similar function in R, and the code of Henrik Bengtsson originates from long before the obligatory namespaces as introduced in R 2.14. I remember I've seen other ways of achieving the same, but can't locate them.

EDIT : I'm specifically looking for S3. The function `isGeneric()` only works for S4, eg for `anova` (which is a S3 generic) :

```
> isGeneric('anova')
[1] FALSE
> anova
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("anova")
<bytecode: 0x04dc7a18>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Comment: See `?isGeneric` in the 'methods' package.

Comment: @DWin That's S4, not S3.

Comment: Maybe: `isGenericS3 = function(FUN) body(match.fun(FUN))[[1]] == 'UseMethod'`. Perhaps there is a more general solution as I believe some base methods dispatch internally without visibly using UseMethod.

Comment: @Charles I'm thinking along the same lines. Problem starts if you want to use that to determine whether or not you have to create an S3 generic within your package...

Comment: Interesting question. If you end up needing to piece something together, `.knownS3Generics` might be useful. It does know about base group generic functions (e.g. `Math` and `Ops`) that don't include `'UseMethod'" in their body.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : Thx for the tip! very useful indeed.

Comment: So Josh, whey not post as answer  `isS3Generic<- function(fname) fname %in% names(.knownS3Generics)` and get this off the unanswered queue?

Comment: Or if you want to work on the unquoted actual function name then `isS3Generic<- function(fname) gsub("\\(|\\)", "", deparse(sys.call()[2])) %in% names(.knownS3Generics)`

Comment: @DWin because that only recognizes the ones in that list. You could copy the code from the link I gave and update it to R 2.14 which is what I was planning to do if I find the time somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isGenericS3` function of the `R.methodsS3` package. Please see the code below:

```
library(R.methodsS3)
isGenericS3(anova)
# [1] TRUE
```