# How to conditionally define a generic function in R NAMESPACE

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm working with two R packages ([network](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) and [sna](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sna/index.html)) that are essentially 'peers': they Suggest each other and supply compatible and related functionality.  Unfortunately, they both define the '%c%' operator, so loading the second package gives a warning:

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:sna’: %c%
```

This seems like perfect job for S3 generics-- the network package can define `%c%.network` , sna can define `%c%.matrix`, with the dispatching handled appropriately by a `%c%` generic.  The problem is, since both packages need to work independently, how do I define and export the generic to avoid the warning?

I've tried putting code like the following in both NAMESPACE files so that whichever loads first can define the generic:

```
if (!exists('%c%')){ 
  export(`%c%`)
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  What is the correct way to handle this sort of conditional function definition and namespace export?

Edit:
Did a little digging into the parsing of R NAMESPACE file in the R src (https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-3-1-branch/src/library/base/R/namespace.R). Seems like 'if' is supported, and its argument should be eval()'d, but I guess this must happen in an environment that the functions loaded by namespace are not yet attached to?

Comment: Some resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474872/safely-creating-s3-generics-in-r http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.methodsS3/index.html https://github.com/cran/R.methodsS3

Comment: If you want a generic to be used by both packages, you need to create a package that defines the generic and is imported by both packages.

Comment: @hadley I think CRAN will frown upon us creating a package with only a single method.

Comment: @GaborCsardi looked into R.methodsS3 internals to see how it does it. Seems to use assign() to conditionally generate a generic, but perhaps doesn't add it to the namespace?

Comment: A package with a single function is fine, and I believe it's the right  way to solve this problem.